# Unable to extract string using this regex expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string whose first character is "^". I want to extract the string without this character. For eg : "^coal" should become "coal". Following is the code I wrote, but I don't know why it's not working.

```
public void RegEx(String s1){
        System.out.println(s1.substring(0,1));  //to check if i am ok.
        if((s1.substring(0,1)).equals("^")){
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^");
            String[] extracted = p.split(s1);
            for(String s: extracted){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

s1 = "^coal".  Output = "^coal".

Comment: I'm not a javascript expert, but if you're trying to remove the first character, can't you just do `s1 = s1.substring(1);` inside your `if` statement? For example, `"MyString".substring(1);` evaluates to `"yString"`

Comment: This is just a fragment of a larger problem. So I really need to know the official way. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^` character has special meaning in a regex so you need to escape it: `"\\^"`.

But a regex is not the most efficient way to do this. Just use `substring`:

```
if (s1.startsWith("^")) {
    s1 = s1.substring(1);
}
System.out.println(s1);
```

*Note:* as you see above you can also use `startsWith` to easily check if a string starts with some other string.

Comment: Knew I shoulda posted my comment as an answer :) +1!

Answer (score 1):

The character `^` is significant in a regular expression. Escape it like,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\^");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this using indexOf method. It is short and more efficient

```
 String s="^coal";
 int l=s.indexOf("^");
 System.out.println(s.substring(l+1));
```